# How to trigger loading state after data came once in SWR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swr

I have a table component just like in the image. There is a refresh button on right top. When user click it, I'm refetching the table by using mutate() but isLoading not becoming true so that loading spinner not showing. I want to make user know that table is refetching the data by showing the loading indicator.

My current line for fetching data:

`const { data: originalData, isLoading, mutate } = useSWR(fetch-table, fetcher);`

Table component:

[image]

Is there a way to make isLoading true after data came once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cache.delete feature in SWR. We need to delete cache to see the loading state again.

```
import useSWR, { useSWRConfig } from 'swr';
    
const { data: originalData, isLoading, mutate } = useSWR("fetch-table", fetcher);    
const { cache } = useSWRConfig();    

const onRefresh = () => {
  cache.delete("fetch-table") //fetch-table is your req key.
  mutate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `mutate` do nothing because of the cache, try to check it in the browser. Also, you can provide cache control parameters to the mutate function. Check revalidate section in the documentation here: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#api

Comment: It looks like mutate is working even the data cached, I can see the request going in network tab. You can checkout my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

SWR has another boolean that you can pull out of the hook called `isValidating`. If you use the keyed mutate destructured from the hook the `isValidating` will be set to true. So in this case, if you want your table to show the loading icon when you hit refresh and call `mutate` you can set your table loading state to `(isLoading || isValidating)`

`const { data: originalData, isLoading, isValidating, mutate } = useSWR(fetch-table, fetcher);`

`isLoading`: will only be true if there is no cache data and SWR is fetching it.

`isValidating`: will be set to true if there is cached data and SWR is fetching updated date

See the SWR docs for more info https://swr.vercel.app/docs/api#return-values